# Remove pagination text from MUI's TablePagination component that shows the rows per page and the total rows in the table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using MUI's tablePagination component in my table in React with TypeScript, where i want to remove/disable the circlemarked text shown in the picture(the pic is an example from mui)
[image]

From what i can see from the documentation of the tablePagination, i think i need to use the labelDisplayedRows prop but i can see it takes in a function so i'm not quite sure how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target `MuiTablePagination-displayedRows` class of the `<TablePagination/>` component to remove rows count text in it. Check the solution below.

```
<TablePagination
    sx={{ "& .MuiTablePagination-displayedRows": { display: "none" }
     }}
  />
```